# Checkbox Sizing in OpenTBS

Tags: opentbs, tinybutstrong

OpenTBS makes it easy to check off Form Control checkboxes in a template while merging data into the template. All one must do is edit the checkbox's properties to have an onload code (ex: [onload.yellow]) and then have php set the code to 'checked' (ex: $yellow='checked';).

The problem I am having is that the Form Control checkboxes cannot be resized in any way that I can find. LibreOffice, OpenOffice, and MS Office do not seem to allow it. I am wondering if OpenTBS provides an easy-ish solution to this issue.

So far, the only solution I can think of is to use OpenTBS's image-replacement tools; I would put an image of an unchecked box on the template and then replace it with an image of a checked box when merging data into the template. This would be very clunky and so it is not a desirable solution.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: This seems not related to OpenTBS nore TBS, rather to LibreOffice and Ms Office

Comment: I didn't explain as well as I could have. I will update my original question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using UI controls in your documents (LibreOffice, Ms Office, ...) those controls are dedicated to the computer user interface. That's why you cannot manage them as you whish, including resizing.

Nevertheless, if your goal is to display a checkbox not dedicated to UI, you can use the UTF8 characters :

- ☐ ballot box
- ☑ ballot box with check
- ☒ ballot box with x
- ballot box with bold script x

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I don't believe this can be accomplished using OpenTBS, but I will keep it in mind.

Comment: Think about conditional display with OpenTBS. I could help i you explain what is the problem with OpenTBS.

Comment: @Skrol29 How can I display checkbox in my document?

Comment: @MuhammadSaadShahid you should open a new question

Comment: @Skrol29 I already posted new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53491915/opentbs-how-can-i-insert-checkbox-in-docx-file-using-php